# Do we use noun or an adjective to describe a thing?

Tags: adjectives, nouns

Today in the morning I was walking with my friend on the street. We came across two buildings which were identical. My friend pointed his finger to the two building and said, "symmetry." What he meant that the buildings were exact copies of each other. So I said to him that he should have used an adjective to describe the similarity of the design of the two building.

He did not agree. Am I correct or he?

Comment: Adjectives modify nouns/pronouns. Based on the context, your friend was pointing out **the existence of symmetry.** (the first building being a mirror image of the other) But if you are to describe the design/approach considering the existence of symmetry, you may say that it is symmetrical (which is an adjective). Take note: the design/approach -> symmetrical. what is existing -> symmetry.

Comment: Should not use an adjective to describe a thing? ***Huge!***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Shin's comment is a good answer. I'd add:

Your friend just said one word, not a complete sentence. So it's meaningless to discuss whether it was grammatically correct.

There are lots of words in English that have a noun form and an adjective form. If your friend had used a complete sentence, he could have said, "Those building are symmetrical", or he could just as well have said, "Those buildings are an example of symmetry". Either would have been grammatically and logically correct, and they both express essentially the same idea.